# Can MongoDB be backed up at a transaction boundary?

Tags: mongodb, transactions, backup

If all operations on a community edition of MongoDB 4.x occur in transactions, are any of the methods for backing up the DB guaranteed to produce a snapshot at a transaction boundary, rather than just at some random state of partial transaction?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is for a [replica set deployment](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/) with default configurations, back-up methods that create backups of a MongoDB system at an exact moment in time (i.e. atomic) would guarantee at a transaction boundary.

With [MongoDB multi-document transactions](https://www.mongodb.com/transactions) only when a transaction commits, all data changes made in the transaction are saved and visible outside the transaction. Also worth mentioning as of MongoDB v4.0.x, there is only a single [opLog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/) entry for all the writes within a single transaction.

See also:

- [Transactions Atomicity](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/#atomicity)
- [Transaction Options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/#transaction-options-read-concern-write-concern-read-preference)
- [MongoDB Backup Methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/) for various back up strategies.